# How to configure STM32f405 SPI to transmit data with DMA?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I have a STM32f405 and the task is to transmit data over the SPI and save processor time with the DMA. The used SPI is SPI1 with pins PA4 to PA7. I've chosen for DMA the 3-rd stream from DMA2 channel 3. The idea is to activate the CS signal and store some data in the memory, which then to be transferred automatically by the DMA and once that's done DMA should trigger an interrupt handler to deactivate the CS. Here is the code:

```
static void SPI_Config(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    SPI_InitTypeDef  SPI_InitStructure;
    DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_Init_Structure;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
    /* Enable the SPI clock */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1,ENABLE);
    /* Enable GPIO clocks */
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    /* Enable DMA clock */
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
    /* SPI GPIO Configuration --------------------------------------------------*/
  /* GPIO Deinitialisation */
    GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA);
    /* Connect SPI pins to AF5 */ 
//  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_SPI1); //SS
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_SPI1); //SCK   
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_SPI1); //MISO
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI1); //MOSI

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_5; //SCK
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure); 

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_6; //MISO
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure); 

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_7; //MOSI
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure); 

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_4; //SS
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure); 

    //DMA Globul Interrupt
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Stream3_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 2;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 3;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    //DMA Configuration
    DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream3);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream3, DISABLE);
    while (DMA1_Stream0->CR & DMA_SxCR_EN);
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_BufferSize = 0;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_3; 
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&spi_tx_val);
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Disable;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t) (&(SPI1->DR));
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    DMA_Init_Structure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
    DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream3,&DMA_Init_Structure);

    //SPI Configuration
    SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI1);
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_256;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low; //AD5620 doku page 18 falling edge of SCLK
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 0; //x_8+x_2+x_1+1 in python hex(2**8+2**2+2+1)
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b; //AD5620 input register is 16 bit
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);




}

int8_t Analog_Out_Config(uint32_t target_reg_val) {
    uint16_t power_on_status;
    target_reg_val = target_reg_val;
    SPI_Config();
//  SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
//  power_on_status=PowerOn_AD5750_OutDriver();
//  if(power_on_status) {
        //enable dma interrupt
//      SPI_Cmd(SPI1, DISABLE);
        DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream3,DMA_IT_TC,ENABLE);
        DMA_ClearFlag(DMA2_Stream3, DMA_FLAG_FEIF3|DMA_FLAG_DMEIF3|DMA_FLAG_TEIF3|DMA_FLAG_HTIF3|DMA_FLAG_TCIF3);
        DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream3, ENABLE);
      SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPI1,SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
        SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

        return power_on_status&0x07;
//  }else {
//      return -1;
//  }
}
void Analog_Output(uint32_t measured_reg_val) {
    val=0x7ff;
    ACTIVATE_CS_DAC();
    spi_tx_val=val; 
}

void DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(DMA_GetITStatus(DMA2_Stream3,DMA_IT_TCIF3)!=RESET) {
        DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA2_Stream3,DMA_IT_TCIF0|DMA_IT_HTIF0);
        DEACTIVATE_CS_DAC();

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    target_reg_val=14;
    measured_reg_val=12;
    Analog_Out_Config(target_reg_val);
  while (1)
  {
        for(val=-target_reg_val;val<target_reg_val;val++) {
            Analog_Output(val);
            for(i=0;i<1000;i++);
        }

  }
}
```

With the debugger I've found out that the DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler is never activated. According to the reference manual DMA should transfer the data when TXE flag from the SPI_DR register is 1, which was so. Also the flag TXDMAEN from the SPI_CR2 was set. I checked the DMA S3CR register too and the flags TCIE and EN were set as well. In addition the function DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler in visible to the main function. Still DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler was never activated.

**UPDATE**: when I manually reset the EN bit of DMA2_S3CR register then the DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler  is triggered. According to the reference manual this bit is cleared by the hardware:

- on a DMA end of transfer (stream ready to be configured)
- if a transfer error occurs on the AHB master buses
- when the FIFO threshold on memory AHB port is not compatible with the
  size of the burst

I've also changed the SPI_Config and the Analog_Out_Config, but still without intervention with the debugger DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler is never triggered. It looks like that the DMA is not triggering the transfer and cannot end it for some reason. How can I find out if DMA has trigger any transfer?

Comment: TL;DR, but as a note, the DMA has to be enabled in the peripheral before the actual transfer is started. One aspect is that you cannot (easily) mix CPU and DMA transfers. (That is also true for e.g. the USART).

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't put all the code here, but in the question, you are not calling `SPI_Config` where you setup your DMA. If this is actually the case, that is probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: @rjp I'm using SPI_Config to set up the SPI including the DMA dedicated to to SPI transmission. But I'm enabling the DMA with Analog_Out_Config function. I have done that before for other parts of the system such as ADC and it's never been a problem.

Comment: @rjp yes you are right there I didn't post part of the code from the Analog_Out_Config function. After the comment of Olaf I think now that it might be relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have your DMA configuration structure setting `DMA_Mode` to `DMA_NORMAL`. It likely should be set to `DMA_PFCTRL` which is peripheral flow control. This will cause the DMA to wait for the signal from the peripheral (which you have configured) rather than run continuously. I would expect, though, that without this setting, you would get one or two words coming out the SPI bus, as `SPI_DR` should get all the memory setup in the DMA transfer dumped on it consecutively (as it is shifting out the first word).

Another thing to check is that none of your peripherals (`SPI1`, `DMA2`) are in reset. I see that you disable the clock, but I don't remember if ST also takes the peripheral out of reset on that call.

**Note**: I used the STM32F2xx DMA peripheral as a reference, but the STM32F4xx peripherals tend to be supersets. It also looks like you're using a different version of the ST Peripheral Library than what I used as a reference.

Comment: The F4 peripherals are practically identical to the F2 ones (I wish some were not...). As an additional note: I'd strongly refuse using the rubbish STlib. It is just bloatware and complicates things unnecessarily. Naming it "HAL" is a mere joke, you have to know the hardware anyway. Just use the peripheral definitions header and write own drivers to encapsulate hardware accesses.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing, though it's been a few years. I've moved on to the Kinetis family, which with KSDK 2.0, actually has some usable drivers (though I still have a few with a portable framework that I did port to the Kinetis peripherals).

Comment: @Programmed both families actually (and quite some others). Still I have to be shown a library which is a match for drivers with direct hardware access. One major issue is that these libraries often enforce a system architecture which does not match what I prefer (and has proven superiour in various projects). These libs tend to stick to an outdated programming style, especially on the Cortex-M3/4/7 which provide interrupt priorities, a very clever multi-threading support, etc. - Harsh words? Maybe. But I have good reasons for them.

Comment: I completely understand. I find that KSDK is usable enough in some cases. I2C is a good example, because every peripheral wants to work differently, and I didn't find the reference manual to be descriptive enough to write a driver without a lot of pain. The driver works (though on the older KSDK, I had to wrap it behind a mutex, as it was not thread safe), so I rolled with it.

Comment: Reference manuals truely is an issue, especially with Freescale. Sad enough, as Motorola used to have some of the best documentation until they split. I really loved the 68K/CPU32 RMs and the HC11/HC08 ones. The K-series are indeed a terrible mess. In that aspect ST is much better. But they also leave out vital details and mess up things, e.g. the CRC module in the F2/4 (uses Ethernet-CRC, but cannot be used with DMA to calcuilate it on a frame due to wrong shift-direction). And ST's compatibility sticking was just ridiculous with F2 already, more with F4 and F7.

Comment: @rjp there is no DMA_PFCTRL defined in sthm32f4xx_dma.h the only possibilities are DMA_Mode_Normal and DMA_Mode_Circular. DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler is not triggered with any of them.

Comment: Hmm, they must have changed how it works on the F4xx then. I would poke around in the header file and check the reference manual to see if this mode still exists, though the API sounds like it may have moved/been removed.